# How to Fetch Function List from wsdl with soap client in php

Tags: php, soap

I have one http: path and one wsdl file.
but it is not work in local ip and server ip.
it is work only mobile.
i want to check this webservice is working is not working.
If working, i want to get function list from wsdl.
How it?

Plz help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 8):

This will list the available functions from the service:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://hostsite');
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BubbleSOAP php script:

```
try{
   $client = new BubbleSOAP($wsdl_url);
   $list=$client->__getFunctionsNames();
   foreach($list as $name){
      echo $name;
   }
}
catch(Exception $e){
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

https://github.com/andreaval/Bubble-SOAP